# R: difference in interpreting estimates of plm and LSDV model?

Tags: r, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

What is the difference in the estimates of plm and least squares dummy variable (LSDV) models? And how does the interpretation of the variables differ in general?

Imagine the following `plm()` and `lm() + factor()`:

```
within <- plm(dependent_var ~ independent_var, data = dataset, method = "within" , effect = "twoways")

LSDV <- lm(dependent_var ~ independent_var + factor(individual) - 1 + factor(time), data = dataset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "within estimator" and the least squares dummy variable (LSDV) estimator yield equivalent estimates of `independent_var`. Including a full series of indicator variables for the panel and/or  temporal identifier is algebraically equivalent to estimation in deviations from means. Though the mechanics may differ, it should not affect your interpretation of `independent_var`.

*Suggestions*:

It isn't necessary to drop the intercept inside of the `lm()` function, though it shouldn't affect your point estimates.

Also, don't forget to set your indexes when using `plm()` to estimate a panel model. Either coerce your data frame using `pdata.frame()`:

```
panel_dataset <- pdata.frame(dataset, index = c("individual", "time"))
```

or, simply set the panel indexes inside of your call to `plm()` after the model formula. The latter approach saves you some extra keystrokes:

```
plm(y ~ x, data = dataset, index = c("individual", "time"), method = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

Comment: Thank you @thomas bilach!!

Comment: Also, don't forget to set your indexes. I'm sure you've already pre-processed the data frame, but I couldn't be sure. I updated my answer with some suggestions.